# File-less Activation with wcf and add service reference wont work?

Tags: wcf

Hi I'm trying out File-less Activation with an silverlight solution, and when I choose add service reference it wont show up, I can browse the service with success in my web browser.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to http://YourServiceUrl.svc?wsdl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't automatically show up, vs.net uses the svc file to locate the service.
I need to do as Ladislav said, type the address into the vs.net service reference manually.